# Rscript, Error check twitter oauth

Tags: r, twitter, rscript

I run the following script using RStudio and twitter package

```
api_key <- " xxx "  
api_secret <- " yyy"  
access_token <- "zzz"  
access_token_secret <- "mmm"  
options(httr_oauth_cache=T)  
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
```

The script works fine, when I run it from Rstudio. However, when I automatically run it via a bat file using Rscript, I get the following error-message:

```
“Using direct authentication”  
Error en check_twitter_oauth() OAuth authentication error:…
```

Any help will be much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I find the solution, just need to put the path to the libraries library('xxx',lib= 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.1/library')